# Python, pygame.image.load() function problem

Tags: python, pygame

I followed a turtorial where I was lerning to create games using pygame. I just started and I already have a problem. It says it has trouble with finding the image. Here is what it says:

```
C:\Users\Patryk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe: 
  can't open file ''
C:\Users\Patryk\PycharmProjects\PePeSza-Game\main.py: [Errno 2]
```

I tried looking for someone with same problem, but couldn't find  the anwser to my question. Here is whole code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

# Game window
screen_width = 800

screen_height = 640

lower_margin = 100

side_margin = 300

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width,screen_height))
screen = pygame.display.set_caption(('Level editor'))

# Importing images
bg_img = pygame.image.load('./bg.png')

# Create function for drawing background
def draw_bg():
    screen.blit('bg_img', (0, 0))

# Mainloop
run = True

while run:

    draw_bg()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question an provide the entire traceback. The error message currently in it doesn't show the filename that cannot be found.

Comment: What's your project's folder and file structure, including where `bg.png` is? It could be an issue with relative paths. If you specify an absolute path instead of a relative one does that work?

Comment: File bg.png is in the same folder as my script. Absolute path doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two thing you need to do in the code

1. removing the ./ before image name. It might be causing issues

```
# Importing images
bg_img = pygame.image.load('bg.png') # removing the ./
```

2. In screen.blit in draw_bg, you were passing string but you need to pass the object made with pygame.image.load

```
# Create function for drawing background
def draw_bg():
    screen.blit(bg_img, (0, 0))  # removing the apostrophe
```

Full code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

# Game window
screen_width = 800

screen_height = 640

lower_margin = 100

side_margin = 300

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width,screen_height))
screen = pygame.display.set_caption(('Level editor'))

# Importing images
bg_img = pygame.image.load('bg.png')

# Create function for drawing background
def draw_bg():
    screen.blit(bg_img, (0, 0))

# Mainloop
run = True

while run:

    draw_bg()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```